# Pagination not working with Firebase scroll reference

Tags: angularjs, pagination, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-util

This is probably a noob question but I am following this [firebase util](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/)
scroll ref pagination to retrieve my data from firebase database. I want to receive only those objects that meet the criteria of user city but its not working as I am not receiving anything in return.

The code I am trying is

```
var baseRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com");
      var norm = new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
          baseRef.child('Events')  // the master index
        );


  // filter the client-side results to only include records where event_city matches user city
  norm = norm.filter(function(data, key, priority) {
     return data.event_city === $rootScope.userCity; // setting $rootScope.userCity initially
  });

  // specify the fields for each path
  norm = norm.select( 'Events.lat', 'Events.lng', 'Events.event_city', 'Events.event_state' );

  var ref = norm.ref();
 var scrollRef = new Firebase.util.Scroll(ref,"event_city");
   $rootScope.events= $firebaseArray(scrollRef);
// load the first ten events
    scrollRef.scroll.next(10);
```

`

My Firebase structure is really simple

```
root :
    Events :{
            -Event1-id :{
                         created_on: 225325223,
                         event_state: "abc",
                         event_city:"äbc",
                         event_desc:"abd",
                         lat : 28.1234567, //event latitude
                         lng : 77.1234567, //event longitude
                         event_address : "abc",
                         event_date : 446343643
                        },
               -Event2-id:{
                            .....
                          },
               -Event3-id:{

                          }....
         }
```

Please help me out. Sorry this is my first question here so let me know if anything else is required.